# Yammer web part for SharePoint 2010 error message

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, yammer

I'm trying to set up the Yammer (version 3.1.4) web part for a SharePoint 2010 Server site. The site is on my university network so assume I only have admin permissions for this site and no access to the central administration. The web part installation itself had to go through a 3 week change process.

Now it is installed I tried adding the web part to the homepage and am faced with the error code below:

```
System.Exception: Unable to load the web part. IsEdit: False, IsAsync: False, FormMode: Display, SharedProperties: {"site_url":"https://spteach.shu.ac.uk/sites/ALEK","service_account":"false","webpart_guid":"9482c9ce-af72-4133-8372-1c25a9222f30","iframe":"true","version":"3.1.3"} at Yammer.SharePoint.WebParts.YammerAppsWebPart.CreateChildControls()
```

Any help as to what the problem is, and even better the solution would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: To update, I'm not sure if this is useful to know or not but the images within the yammer web part when you add it don't seem to link to anything, or at least they are not doing what is demonstrated in this video - https://vimeo.com/76085201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SP2010 web part is going to be discontinued soon so I'd advise you use embed instead - https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/#/Threads/show?threadId=510047230

A new era with Yammer Embed and Sharepoint

Hi everyone,

Over the past years, we’ve provided 3 different solutions to integrate Yammer feeds into SharePoint: the Yammer App for SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online, the Yammer Web Part for SharePoint 2010 and Yammer Embed. Although this provided choice, it also created customer challenges, including IT complexity, unclear user expectations from different UIs, and increased security and support effort, among others.

To minimize these challenges, we are unifying our investments to a single solution going forward: Yammer Embed. With Yammer Embed as our single solution to integrate Yammer feeds, we’ll focus our resources to innovate faster for customers, minimize IT complexity, streamline the end user experience with a single UI, and provide a simple, sustainable model to unlock the power of open team collaboration with Yammer in SharePoint, Office 365 and beyond.

Today, as part of this journey, we are announcing the discontinuation of the Yammer App for SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online, and of the Yammer Web Part for SharePoint 2010. 
The Yammer App for SharePoint 2013 on-premises and SharePoint Online will be discontinued on September 15th, 2015. On this date, the App will stop working completely, and will no longer be supported. Customers on SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint Online must migrate to Yammer Embed, our single solution to embed Yammer feeds going forward, as soon as possible. Please read this step-by-step guide to move to Yammer Embed.
The Yammer Web Part for SharePoint 2010 will be discontinued on March 15th, 2016. On this date, the Web Part will stop working completely, and will no longer be supported. Only SharePoint Online, SharePoint Server 2013, or the upcoming SharePoint Server 2016 release will support Yammer Embed from that point on.

Please read the notes below for further guidance, and reach out to your Microsoft TAM or Account Executive to plan next steps. We truly thank you for coming along in our journey, and for your action to ensure the best Yammer integration experience going forward.

Thank you, 
The Yammer Team

TIMELINE
March 12th, 2015 
Public Announcement on Office 365 Network

Additional channels for specific customers (Message Center, Direct Email)

September 15th, 2015 
Discontinuation of the Yammer App for SharePoint 2013 and SPO

March 15th, 2016 
Discontinuation of the Yammer Web Part for SharePoint 2010

FAQ

Q: Should I expect any functionality updates on the App or Web Part before they are discontinued? 
A: No, during their respective support periods we will not introduce new functionality or improvements. However we will address security issues that may occur during the year.

Q: Should I expect functionality changes when moving from the Yammer App to Yammer Embed in SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint Online?

A: The functionality changes are minimal. The main difference is the way Yammer Embed is added to a site. Please read this step-by-step guide to move from the Yammer App to Yammer Embed.

Q: What are some of the issues with the Yammer App for SharePoint 2013 and the Yammer Web Part for SP2010?

A: The Yammer App for SharePoint 2013 requires manual intervention to update each app instance on your SharePoint sites. With Yammer Embed, on the other hand, every instance is up-to-date with no manual intervention, across SharePoint. This a significantly more convenient model which decreases support and maintenance costs and helps businesses get Yammer Embed innovations as soon as they are released.

The Yammer Web Part for SharePoint 2010 uses legacy technology, including OAuth v1.0 and SP2010's reliance on IE8 mode to render pages for all browsers, both of which restrict the use of Yammer Embed on SharePoint 2010, are not supported by Yammer, and limit our ability to innovate and deliver value to customers.

Q: When does mainstream support end for SharePoint 2010? 
A: Mainstream support for SharePoint 2010 ends in October 2015. See more here.

Q: Can I reach out to my Microsoft TAM or Account Executive regarding this issue?
Yes, we strongly recommend you reach out to your Microsoft TAM or Account Executive to plan next steps if necessary.